# How to check the age from input and perform the appropriate conditional statement?

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm taking steps back to relearn my foundations on javascript (and realizing that it's a lot shakier than what I've thought). Maybe I just need fresh eyes, but I'm not seeing where the error lies in the code.

( *Lot of the things I've read online when I tried to search for answers already had a given age ie. var age = # for the conditionals, but not where it varied based on user input.* )

Your help is greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!

```js
const ageInput = document.querySelector("#ageInput");
const paraContent3 = document.querySelector(".paractice3-p");
const enter = document.querySelector(".enter");

function checkAge() {
  const age = ageInput.innerHTML;
  if (age < 10) {
    paraContent3.innerHTML = "You would roughly be in elementary";
  } else if (age < 14) {
    paraContent3.innerHTML = "You would roughly be in middle school";
  } else if (age < 18) {
    paraContent3.innerHTML = "You would roughly be in high school";
  } else {
    paraContent3.innerHTML = "You're out of school!";
  }
}

enter.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
  if (e.target == 13) {
    checkAge();
  }
});
```

```css
#practice3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}
#practice3 h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#practice3 input {
  text-align: center;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  padding: 10px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
#practice3 .enter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

```html
<section id="practice3">
  <h1>what is your age?</h1>
  <input id="ageInput" type="number" min="1" placeholder="enter your age">
  <p class= "practice3-p"></p>
  <button class="enter">enter</button>
</section>
```

Comment: If you want the value of an input, use value, not innerHTML: `ageInput.value`.

Comment: hello! I tried both the ageInput.value and parseInt(ageInput.innerHTML) but neither still shows the words ("you're almost in ____") :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have mixed multiple things. I think you are trying to use Jquery. I have modified your code little bit, you can change according to your requirement. Let me know if you still face issue.

```
<section id="practice3">
  <h1>what is your age?</h1>
  <input id="ageInput" type="number" min="1" placeholder="enter your age">
  <p class= "practice3-p" id="showMessage"></p>
  <button class="enter" onClick="checkAge()">enter</button>
</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
<script>
function checkAge() {
    const ageInput = $("#ageInput").val();
    const paraContent3 = $("#showMessage");
    const enter = $(".enter");
    const age = parseInt(ageInput);
  if (age < 10) {
    paraContent3.text("You would roughly be in elementary");
  } else if (age < 14) {
    paraContent3.text("You would roughly be in middle school");
  } else if (age < 18) {
    paraContent3.text("You would roughly be in high school");
  } else {
    paraContent3.text("You're out of school!");
  }
}
/*
enter.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
  if (e.target == 13) {
    checkAge();
  }
});*/
  </script>
```

Comment: Hi Amit, thank you for your patience! I had a test that I had to study for and didn't have time to go over the code. But it works well now! And jQuery was a lot easier to understand than using vanilla JS (or attempts to). :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const age = ageInput.innerHTML
```

will be

```
const age = parseInt(ageInput.innerHTML)
```

Comment: hello! I tried both the ageInput.value and parseInt(ageInput.innerHTML) but neither still shows the words ("you're almost in ____") :(